# XML Schema Error: Required white space was missing

Tags: xml, xsd, vb.net-2010, sqlxml, bulk-load

I have been searching on this for hours and can not figure out the issue. Could someone please help me with this? I am getting the above error when Executing a SQLXMLBULKLOAD in VB.NET 2010. I have attempted changing my xml declaration, my schema attributes, on and on and can not get past this error. It seems to be trivial but I can not figure it out. Please help

```
        <?xml version="1.0" ?>
     <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:mapping-schema">
        <xsd:element name="Employees" sql:is-constant="1">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xsd:element name="Employee" sql:relation="the_Employees">
                        <xsd:complexType>
                            <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <!--<xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:integer" />-->
                                <xsd:element name="EmployeeID"sql:field="EmpNo">
                                    <xsd:simpleType>
                                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                            <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                        </xsd:restriction>
                                    </xsd:simpleType>
                                </xsd:element>
                                <xsd:element name="FirstName"sql:field="FirstName">
                                <xsd:simpleType>
                                    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xsd:restriction>
                                </xsd:simpleType>
                            </xsd:element>
                            </xsd:sequence>
                        </xsd:complexType>
                    </xsd:element>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need a space between attributes.

Like this one in line 10.

```
<xsd:element name="EmployeeID"sql:field="EmpNo">
```

should be

```
<xsd:element name="EmployeeID" sql:field="EmpNo">
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer! Just needed another set of eyes. Thanks!

Comment: You have one at line 17 as well. After that you are good to go.

Answer (score 2):

And on this one in line 16 you need a space. otherwise, you are good to go:

`<xsd:element name="FirstName"sql:field="FirstName">`

change to:

`<xsd:element name="FirstName" sql:field="FirstName">`